# Gradle in Android Studio giving error Project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am new to Android Studio.I installed Android Studio-1.2.1.1 and i have jdk1.7.0_40 installed.I am facing problem with gradle build.
For reference you can check [gradle issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2803)

I am getting following error in messages

```
Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40' but was: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
<a href="open.project.structure">Open JDK Settings</a>
```

All i understood is gradle is using JRE and Android Studio is using JDK and due to that two JAVA_HOME's are different and giving errors.

I tried downloading gradle 2.3 and changed gradle path in android studio to this file,still same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
I fixed this issue by uninstalling all the jdk installation & updates 
then reinstall only one jdk and assure its env. variables

---

I do not have a solution but I have the same problem
it happens as the android studio opens from java_home/jre thence all JVMs that will fork next will come from this path, while your system varible tells Gradle to get his java.exe from JAVA_HOME

I tried to make gradle read from jre but it falied also i tried to make android studio open from java_home/bin but it falid also

Answer (score 14):

This is a very late answer but I see that a common suggestion is to remove all other jdk's and this is not always the best idea.  You might need older jdk's for different projects.  You can go into the gradle.properties file for the project and enter the following line (varied based on your version):

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

If you are using a different jdk just point to a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre
```

with

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40
```

inside your `JAVA_HOME` variable

Comment: thanks for reply,but my JAVA_HOME is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40  only ,and with this setting it is giving that error

Comment: Click on the URL 'Open JDK Settings'  inside message window

Comment: It is pointing to same location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40

Comment: Have you rebuild the project?

Comment: Have you define JAVA_HOME inside user variable and System both?

Comment: and set Path inside system variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin folder

Comment: thanks for reply,JAVA_HOME is defined only as System variable and path variable also pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin folder

Comment: No,I think problem is with some JAVA_HOME pointing by Studio and gradle

Comment: Try to Create new Project and then runs. Sometime gradle not changes(Syncs).

Comment: Tried creating new project ,same problem

Answer (score 1):

For those who are on OS X El Capitan (v10.10) and end up with the above error message.

In my case there was nothing wrong with Gradle, simply my Java 1.8 was "too new" for Android Studio 1.5 so I had to install older 1.7.

I downloaded it from 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
([jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg?AuthParam=1449919899_ae00ec39d198a0070aff5619f2c6cd90))

After all I had to just update JDK location in the project structure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already had java jdk 7u17 and I also had got same error as FaizAli.

I try to search and done a lot of changes but not success!

Then, I downloaded jdk 7u80 [at this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and installed this jdk.
After that those error gone.

Answer (score 0):

What I found out in my case is that the SDK my project pointed to "broke" and I had to fix its "JDK home path":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is 2019.
For anyone experiencing this issue...
The first thing is to make sure that you correctly set your environment variables as per this instruction: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Which means you should be able to type `javac -version` and `java -version` and get the version number inside your Home directory.

Once you can confirm this, then go to the `Project Structure` inside, the `SDK Location` > `JDK Location` select `Use JAVA_HOME environment variable`.

This was what I did and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by going to `Project Structure` then unchecking `use embedded JDK` and then setting the path to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`

Answer (score -1):

Solved this by going to
File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

and under JDK Location, update with Gradle SDK location.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because Android is using embedded ( JRE ) which is selected as recommended and at same  time  Android Studio detects JDK Home_Path (Environmental Variable ) and due to that two JAVA Path are different there is the conflict so it give you Error :

If You remove java_home  path or Environmental variable you will get this error:

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified [Android studio

For Android Studio, the solution is to go to File> Other Setting > Default Project Structure> [Uncheck the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9dQk.png)
and browse and [set JDK path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnqDY.png)