# Java Home is different? How to set it correctly in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I had got a problem with JAVA Compiler. The JDK change patch in *Project Structure* wasn't working so I edited **jdk.table.xml**:

```
<jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_111&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/deploy.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/javaws.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jfr.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/plugin.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jre/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
```

And also, in *JAVA_HOME* I got:

E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111

Which is the same like in **jdk.table.xml** I can't build 'cause i'm getting:

*Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
Java home is different.
Expecting: 'E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111' but was: 'E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111\jre'.*

Please help guys!

**#EDIT**

Now I've got in *jdk.table.xml*:

```
  <jdk version="2">
      <name value="1.8" />
      <type value="JavaSDK" />
      <version value="java version &quot;1.8.0_111&quot;" />
      <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111" />
      <roots>
        <annotationsPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar!/" />
          </root>
        </annotationsPath>
        <classPath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/charsets.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/deploy.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/javaws.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/jce.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/jfr.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/jsse.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/management-agent.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/plugin.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/resources.jar!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/rt.jar!/" />
          </root>
        </classPath>
        <javadocPath>
          <root type="composite" />
        </javadocPath>
        <sourcePath>
          <root type="composite">
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/src.zip!/" />
            <root type="simple" url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/javafx-src.zip!/" />
          </root>
        </sourcePath>
      </roots>
```

*JAVA_HOME*:

```
E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111
```

*Path:*

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;E:\Program Files\Condusiv Technologies\ExpressCache\;C:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

And still getting:

```
Error:The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
```

Java home is different.
Expecting: 'E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111' but was: 'E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111\jre'.
Please configure the JDK to match the expected one.
Open JDK Settings

Where I need to remove /jre/? What is wrong now?

Comment: Did you restart Android Studio after changing JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Yes I restarted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle in Android Studio giving error Project sync failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642954/gradle-in-android-studio-giving-error-project-sync-failed)

Comment: You can save a lot of time and trouble by googling the error message.

Comment: Nope, check the EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Windows

so you can see this link and setup the JAVA_HOME and PATH

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/

Comment: I think your error ``Java home is different`` is because of the PATH

Comment: I got, check the #EDIT

Comment: In ``.gradle/gradle.properties`` 
``org.gradle.java.home=E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111\jre``

i dont know this works or not

Comment: try ``org.gradle.java.home=E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jdk1.8.0_111`` ?